# How to apply the alphaMaskFilter in Flash CC using Easel.js?

Tags: mask, alpha, createjs, easeljs, flash-cc

I am working in a canvas document using Flash CC and have the following labeled moveclips on the stage mask_mc (which is a movieclip with a alpha gradient) and logo. The objective is to create a sheen going across the logo.

```
var mask_mc = this.mask_mc; 
mask_mc.cache(0, 0, 232, 196);

var logo = this.logo;
logo.cache(0, 0, 271, 40);

logo.filters = [
new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(mask_mc.cacheCanvas)
];
```

All I am trying to do is emulate what an alpha gradient mask used to do using AS3, but can't get it to work with the above code:

```
//Original AS3 code
mask_mc.cacheAsBitmap = true;
logo.cacheAsBitmap = true;
logo.mask = mask_mc;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cache (or updateCache) *after* you apply the filter(s)

```
var logo = this.logo;
logo.filters = [
    new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(mask_mc.cacheCanvas)
];
logo.cache(0, 0, 271, 40);
```

Your second example will not work because the `mask` property requires a Shape, and will not work with a canvas/cache.

Comment: What I actually wanted to achieve was to have the alpha gradient display object (mask_mc) be masked by the logo instance, which works fine, however there appears to be another instance of the logo appearing below the masked content, although the only 2 instances on the stage are mask_mc and logo. Here is my code:

`var mask_mc = this.mask_mc; 
var logo = this.logo;

logo.x = 0;
mask_mc.x = 0;

logo.cache(0, 0, 271, 40);

mask_mc.filters = [
     new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(logo.cacheCanvas)
 ];

 mask_mc.cache(0, 0, 232, 196);`